# Relating tables in ModelBuilder of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder

I am an intermediate user of ArcMap (version 10x), and the process that I do manually is:

I relate the table of a feature class (representing parcels, cadastral division of a city) to another table that contains data of the real estate market (offering for sale,  sales records values ​​actually realized). The common field for the relationship that I use is the  number of the parcel, and I use the relationship of tables because it is a one-to-many relation.

When operated manually, I select the records in the table with data from the real estate market and the relationship automatically selected table records in the feature class "parcels" (with the same number)  and, from this selection I create a new layer  representing the parcels of the city about which you have a real estate information.

At this point, the result is satisfactory, the problem I have is when I want to automate the process with ModelBuilder, especially when trying to relate the tables, as the relationship does not appear as a tool in ArcToolbox

How do I implement the process described in ModelBuilder?

---

I'll try to explain better:I have a shapefile and its attribute table ("table "1") has a field called "padron"  whose number identifies each parcel.Also I have a table (table "2") with real estate market's data relating the price of homes for sale with  the registration number of the parcel (field called "padron" too).
Sometimes, it may be that there are several houses in a parcel (therefore with the same number in "padron"). In this cases, in the table "2" each house is identified  with a different record's number in a field called "UNIDAD".
For example:
Shapefile attribute table ("1"):

OBJECTID    SHAPE   **PADRON**  SHAPE_LENGTH    SHAPE_AREA

2784    Polygon **999** 82.1389 339.2183

4596    Polygon **998** 59.1372 204.4819

4487    Polygon **997** 61.0052 211.9868

And  Data table ("2"):

OID DATE    **PADRON**  **UNIDAD**  VALUE

15  09/19/2011  **1289**    *0* 87000

16  06/16/2011  **999** ***05***    45000

17  08/16/2011  **119** *0* 73000

23  07/20/2011  **43**  *0* 52000

31  05/02/2012  **999** ***03***    92000

When I do  (manually in ArcMap)  a "relate"  ( notes that the relation is one to many) betwen the  layer of shapefile and the table "2" , finally I can export the selected features and  finally get a new layer with all data, including the same PADRON values and different records in each UNIDAD. But, I could not do this procedure (relate tables and export new layer) in the ModelBuilder. I could make a join , but this tool  not maintain all records where there are several houses on the same parcel (same "padron"'s record and different "unidad"'s record).

Answer (score 0):

Here are two sources of information that should help you:

http://nodedangles.wordpress.com/2010/08/11/trying-to-perform-relate-in-model-builder/

http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1728&t=257179&g=1

and the ESRI help page on relating and joining tables:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s0000002n000000

Comment: I worked with the information you've suggested me but obviously my knowledge is not enough to solve the problem. Thanks anyway.